# Why is this undefined on global level when using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import Store from "./store/store";

console.log(this); //undefined

ReactDOM.render(
  <Store>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Store>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

My guess is that webpack and babel intercept and somehow change the "this"?

Comment: cmiiw, but you can only use `this` in react js only inside class component

Comment: This is not a class, thus, ```this``` is not referring to anything.

Comment: But "this", on the global level in javascript should point to the global (window) object?

Comment: You're in a module, so your code is not running in the global level, and `this` is not the global.